# Docker container naming changed to hypens on local machine

Tags: linux, macos, docker, infrastructure

I use docker with `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` to dynamically create container names. Somewhere in the last 2 months something changed and my local machine generates container names with `hypens`.

e.g `project-name-traefik-1` instead of `project-name_traefik_1`.

How can I change this behavior as this breaks functionality on my linux docker server which for some reason keeps the old container naming structure.

I have the latest Docker Desktop and the latest Docker on the server. I can't find anything in the documentation that points to this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resorted to adding `container_name` (which wasn't previously needed).

I'm also using the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable to get predictable container names.

E.g.

```yaml
...
    nginx:
        image: graffino/nginx:v1
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-nginx
...
```